# One way DB synchronization using mssql Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I am doing DB synchronization via MSSQL Replication utility which is performing well to me.

**Now my objective: after transfer data to destination DB's table, remove transferred data from the source DB's table.**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

*If this is not feasible what are the other approaches to accomplish this?*

Comment: Obviously if you remove from the source, it will replicate this removal to the target. What is minimum latency required (1 minute 1 hour 1 day?) Is this purely for archiving purposes? Are you archiving to improve performance? Are you using a particular field(s) to decide what to archive?

Comment: If you answer some of the questions in my previous commment I may be able to help

Comment: Thanks, hope this helps you.
What is minimum latency required (1 minute 1 hour 1 day?): Ans: 1 min or less. This is live data.
Are you archiving to improve performance?  & Is this purely for archiving purposes? : Ans: no, its for deleting consumed data which have no future use.
Are you using a particular field(s) to decide what to archive? Ans: Complete Row needs to be delete

Comment: Maybe this is useful? It's also much simpler than replication or any custom trigger based solution https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-server-stretch-database/#overview